# Laravel: Cannot pass the array from databse from router to view

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I just started with Laravel and got stuck when I tried to retrieve values from databse and tried to output them on the view through the router. Here's my code in router:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    $posts =  DB::select("select title from posts");
    return View::make("hello", $posts);
});
```

Code in view using blade template:

```
@extends('master')

@section('title')
    @foreach ($posts as $post) {
        {{ $post->title }}
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

I tried to check the query and it runs perfectly, but I get the undefined variable error on the viewed page.

[image]

What is it that I'm doing wrong and how do I correct it? Please help..

Comment: Give this ago. $posts = DB::table(‘posts’)->select(‘title’)->get();

Comment: Error got changed but still not working.
http://puu.sh/7eKGI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$posts = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT title FROM posts'));
```

or:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select('title')->get();
```

And returning View:

```
return View::make('hello', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

You need to assign the `$posts` to a variable before sending to the view. In the above, the variable is `posts`.

Comment: The query result was the same anyway; but the returning view was making all the problem. Thanks a lot for helping, works perfectly now! :D